# Should there be an "Electronegativity" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Here's a [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13677/electronegativity-of-potassium-pauling) to a recent question entitled, "Electronegativity of Potassium (Pauling)".  The OP tagged the question under "Resources" and writes, "Sorry for the lack of tags, I don't know under what tags I could throw this question."  There have also been some other recent questions (pKa of HX acids) where an "Electronegativity" tag would have been useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created [electronegativity](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronegativity). I think it definitely deserves its own tag. I did not search for those other questions, so if you happen to come across one, please retag if it's appropriate.